# Display fullscreen video from one monitor in a window on another monitor

Tags: debian, i3

I have one display connected to DVI and another connected to DisplayPort. I want to capture the video from the first one and display it in a window on the second one. My first idea was to use screen recording software to record video from monitor A and display the recording in a window on monitor B, but I don't know how to do that in real time, and it seems like a sloppy solution.

My second idea was to stream to Twitch and have the stream open in a window, but I don't want to deal with latency and poor quality.

Can I just take the raw output and stream it to a window or something?

Distro is Debian and window manager is i3

Update: I'm now using the preview window in OBS and it's working alright, but I'd still like a better solution.

```
xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384                                                               
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                           
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm                                          
   1920x1080     60.00*+                                                                                                          
   1680x1050     59.95                                                                                                            
   1600x1200     60.00                                                                                                            
   1600x900      60.00                                                                                                            
   1440x900      59.89                                                                                                            
   1400x1050     59.98                                                                                                            
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02                                                                                                   
   1280x960      60.00                                                                                                            
   1280x800      59.81                                                                                                            
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00                                                                                          
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25                                                                                 
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94                                                                                          
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                    
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                      
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: There are `xmag` and `xzoom`, which magnify parts of your current screen. Possibly these programs can be adapted to do the same with minifaction and for a different screen, but I don't know any ready-made program that does that.